# Regular expression to split base and exponent

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to figure out a way to split the base from the exponent.

For instance,

> 3^2  ---> (3, 2)
>
> A ^ 3 ---> (A, 3)
>
> A ^ B ---> (A, B)
>
> A ^ (B + 3) ---> (A, B + 3)

My current hypothesis is as follows:

Base and exponent are either defined by expressions between the parenthesis next to the  '^' (caret), or the characters after/before the closest operators.

Something along the lines of (forgive the terrible excuse for pseudo code)

```
// base:  
if (parenthesis before caret) {base = characters between parenthesis}  
else {base = characters after previous ('+' || '-' || '/')}

// exponent:  
if (parenthesis after caret) {exponent = characters between parenthesis} 
else {exponent = characters before following ('+' || '-' || '/')}
```

Many thanks

Comment: Are you trying to make a calculator?

Comment: @KunalB.: it seems so, given the OP's pseudo-code.

Comment: I think that regular expression is not a solution here. You should do a language parser (read char by char)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the function split. So:

```
var calculation = "4^3";
var splitted = calculation.split("^");
var base = splitted[0];
var exp = splitted[1];
```

If I got it wrong then let me know :)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that only works in isolation

Let's say we have 3 ^ 4 + 3 * 2

What we want is power(3,4) + 3 * 2 = power(3,4) + 6 

rather than power (3, 4 + 3 * 2)

Comment: I gave solution for your examples. But yes, this way it is not working and you need to work with regex I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Would a regex like this be useful?

```
var base = string.replace(/\^.*$/, '');
var exp = string.replace(/^.*\^/, '');
```

`\^.*$` everything to the right of the caret
`^.*\^` everything to the left of the caret
See https://eval.in/171423

Comment: Would that account for situations where there are parenthesis? 

e.g. 15^(5+3) would become power(15,5), rather than power(15,5+3), right?

Comment: base would become 15 and exp would become (5+3), see updated link.

Answer (score 0):

To split Base and Exponent, RegEx you need is

```
\s{0,}\^[\s]{0,}\({0,}
```

[Check-Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bQ3bD4/1)

```
var expStr = 'A^(B+25)';
var res = expStr.split(/\s{0,}\^[\s]{0,}\({0,}/).join(",").split(")").join("")
var converted = "(" + res + ")"
console.log(converted)
//(A,B+25)

//input - '3 ^ 2'
//output - (3,2)

//input - A ^ B
//output - (A,B)
```